# Proving the Cauchy-Bolzano criterion for uniform convergence of sequences of functions by contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

**Theorem**

> *Let sequence $\{f_n(x)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be defined on $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Sequence $\{f_n(x)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ uniformly converges on $D$ iff $\hspace{0.1cm} \forall\varepsilon>0 \hspace{0.1cm} \exists n_0=n_0(\varepsilon)$ s.t. $\hspace{0.1cm} \forall x\in D$ and $\hspace{0.1cm} \forall m,n\geq n_0$, it holds that $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<\varepsilon$.*

I'm struggling to understand the second part of this proof ($\impliedby$), so I tried doing it another way, essentially by contradiction. I got stuck with it, so I don't even know if it is possible. Here it is:

**Proof** ($\impliedby$)

> Let's prove this by contradiction. Let's say that $\{f_n(x)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ diverges on $D$. That means that $\forall\varepsilon>0 \hspace{0.1cm} \exists n_0=n_0(\varepsilon)$ s.t. $\hspace{0.1cm} \forall x\in D$ and $\hspace{0.1cm} \forall n\geq n_0$, it holds that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq\varepsilon$, and also $\forall\varepsilon>0 \hspace{0.1cm} \exists n_0=n_0(\varepsilon)$ s.t. $\hspace{0.1cm} \forall x\in D$ and $\hspace{0.1cm} \forall m\geq n_0$, it holds that $|f_m(x)-f(x)|\geq\varepsilon$. 
> From Here we can see that $|f_m(x)-f(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq2\varepsilon>\varepsilon$.

This is where I get stuck. I can't figure out the connection between the last $|f_m(x)-f(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq2\varepsilon>\varepsilon$ and $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<\varepsilon$. If I did we could just arrive at the $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\geq\varepsilon$, which would be a contradiction. Is this even possible? If so how? If not could I get the explananation for the regular proof of second part in this theorem.

Comment: Your contradiction should be that $\exists \epsilon>0 : \forall n \exists x \in D : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \ge \epsilon$
It is probably possible to prove the result in this way, but onestly i can't see how

Comment: What do you mean "uniformly divergent", do you invent this word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can connect both with that proceeding. The usual proof is direct, as given $\epsilon>0$, there exist some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such as for every $n,m\geq n_0$, we have that $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\leq\epsilon,$ for every $x\in D$. So for every $x\in\ D$, the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, so we can define for every $x\in D$, the limit $$f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x).$$ If we make $m$ tend to infinity in $$|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\leq\epsilon,$$ we get that $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon,$$ for $n\geq n_0$. Since it does not depend on the choice of $x\in D$, we have uniform convergence of the sequence $\{f_n\}$.

Comment: you need first prove it is pointwisely convergent to $f(x)$

Comment: That's exactly  this step "So for every $x\in\ D$, the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, so we can define for every $x\in D$, the limit $$f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$$."

Comment: Surely I understand it is Cauchy, but the OP shows the author is a beginner, do you think what you wrote can gain full mark if this is a problem in the test paper?

Comment: That's the proof that appears in Bartle and Sherbert, a very begginer book

Comment: The author asks for how to proceed on making contradictions, but you wrote the opposite way, what is the point for your answer here? If just look for a correct proof, why not just check the textbook?

Comment: @GGplay just to clarify, I've asked for explanation for regular proof if proof by contradiction isn't possible. The proof from my lecture was very confusing, but essentially the same thing as the one written in this answer. I've approved it so I don't see any problem with it, it answered my question